# Initialization of a counter in max msp

Tags: dictionary, audio, counter, max-msp-jitter

How can I use a type of counter system where not necessarily it starts in 1? for instance the normal counter is counter 0 1 100 where I don't want to start in 1 but in a different number?

Answer (score 2):

The counter object in Max Msp accepts optional arguments after the object name.

- **If there are no arguments** the direction is of the counter is, the minimum is 0, and the maximum is 2,147,483,647 (the largest possible 32-bit signed integer).
- **If there is one argument** it sets an initial maximum count value for counter.
- **If there are two argument** the first number sets an initial minimum value, and the second number sets an initial maximum value.
- **If there are three argument**  the first number specifies the direction of the count, the second number is the minimum, and the third number is the maximum.

[image: Four different kinds of counters]

So to answer your question, if you wanted a counter that counted up to 100 starting from, for example, 5, you would create an object writing:

"counter 0 5 100"

As you can see in the last counter shown in the picture.

Answer (score 0):

to change a 1 into a 7, you would do [+ 6]

also, counter has an inlet which you can feed a number to set the next step.